# How to specify a day and a shop/office/etc. when asking for business hours?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-は

I'm very sorry this is a very basic Question, I just started learning japanese as my third language (german being my native one and english my second) and Right now I learned a basic way of asking for Business Hours, what time it is Right now etc.

But I came across something I couldn't find explained:
I can ask "When does the postoffice close" or "When does it (which was mentioned beforehand so I don't have to repeat it here) close tomorrow" But I can't put both in one sentence like "When does the postoffice close tomorrow" 
I hope you get what I mean?
With my very limited Knowledge Right now I would Need to put two particles to mark the subject of my sentence, which I can't do as far as I'm concerned.

I'm grateful for every help or someone who can tell me where this has already been answered.

Comment: You say you want to merge two sentences that you can write in Japanese. Please provide your versions of these independent sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier way to ask for this information could be:

> 明日{あす}の **営業時間{えいぎょうじかん}** は何時{なんじ}ですか？

営業時間 means the "operating hours" and is a very common way *(especially on the phone)* to ask when a business or office will be open or closed.

Normally the response will be something like:

- 朝{あさ}[10時]{じゅうじ}から[5時半]{ごじはん}です

So now you would know when the place opens and when it closes.

Comment: The OP knows how to write 2 sentences, but not how to combine them. Otherwise this would be just open and closed 'we want to translations'.

Comment: 「営業時間は何ですか？」とは言わないですね・・・　「営業時間は、」から始めるなら、「何時から何時までですか？」とか、「何時からですか？」とか、「何時までですか？」とかね。。。

Comment: @Chocolate「営業時間は何時ですか」はOKですね？それとも？

Comment: ^ その文、ググったら使ってる人結構いますねぇ・・